# Can we run two thread groups parallely in a single test plan in Jmeter?

Tags: testing, jmeter, performance-testing

can we run two thread groups parallel by creating a single test plan in Jmeter ??

Example:

I have to add 2 test cases in a test plan, which has to be executed in parallel and can we combine this test plan with any other test plan to be executed simultaneously

Comment: you can run same test plan from two machines via JMeter Distributed Testing http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.pdf

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Jmeter supports running more than one scenario in parallel as part of the same test plan.

Each scenario is managed in its own Thread Group element.

So for your case, add a new Thread Group to the test plan, and set the steps for the second scenario there. When you have more than 1 Thread Group, you can configure the test plan to start them at the same time (or one after the other).

There is no guarantee that the requests will be in the exact same time, but both Thread Groups will start simultaneously.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: How to implement this programmatically?

Comment: But how can we add a delay time suppose for 10 seconds in between these two thread groups ??