# Jmeter: Test plan has two thread groups but it generated only 1 jtl report

Tags: multithreading, maven, jmeter, jmeter-maven-plugin

My Jmeter Test Plan has two threads. Both threads requires separate CSV (csv parameterization) files.

At the end of test `mvn verify` I expect two `.jtl` files generated, but get only one. Seems only 1 thread is running. When I run in GUI then it works fine, without maven.

**Test Plan:**
[image]

**POM.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.demo.performancetesting</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo-performance-testing</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jmeter-tests</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jmeter</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmeter-graph-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <inputFile>${project.build.directory}/jmeter/results/*.jtl</inputFile>
                    <graphs>
                        <graph>
                            <pluginType>ResponseTimesOverTime</pluginType>
                            <width>800</width>
                            <height>600</height>
                            <outputFile>${project.build.directory}/jmeter/results/BlazeDemoRequest.png</outputFile>
                        </graph>
                    </graphs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I have already gone through these posts but no luck:

[Can we run two thread groups parallely in a single test plan in Jmeter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24239003/can-we-run-two-thread-groups-parallely-in-a-single-test-plan-in-jmeter)

[Why only 2 out 3 JMeter Thread group execute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42427303/why-only-2-out-3-jmeter-thread-group-execute)

I am using Windows 7, Maven 3, Jmeter Maven Plugin

Comment: can you show how you configured the listeners that export jtl ? and also show your pom.xml

Comment: Added pom and testplan. I dont have any listeners to generate `.jtl`. Perhaps `jmeter-maven-plugin` is doing it for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have 2 .jtl files generated only in 2 cases:

1. You have 2 .jmx scripts under `src/test/jmeter` folder
2. You enable [Aggregate Report](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Aggregate_Report) listeners and configure them to save results to `../results` folder prefixed by the test name or [__threadGroupName()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadGroupName) (the function is available since [JMeter 5.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what-is-new-jmeter-5))

---

In general in case of any unexpected behaviour of your JMeter test get used to look at *jmeter.log* file, in case of JMeter tests execution via Maven plugin the log file(s) is(are) located under `target/jmeter/logs` folder relative to your main *pom.xml* file. Normally it should contain enough troubleshooting information to get to the bottom of the issue. The most common reason for JMeter test or thread groups not being executed are:

- incorrect number of threads provided (i.e. failing parameterization)
- dependency file is missing (i.e. CSV file is not being present in expected location)

Comment: I can't recall which one but in some post while answering you suggested not to use listeners in non-gui mode. Is there any other way. I can get reports specific to thread, not combine?

Comment: Unfortunately no. If you really need to have 2 reports you can consider starting with single .jtl results file and using [Filter Results Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FilterResultsTool/) to generate thread-group-specific reports out of the aggregate .jtl file. You can install Filter Results Tool using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager) and invoke it via [Maven Exec Plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/)

Answer (score 1):

You can disable all listeners while running tests as it is recommended.

1. And just add a "Simple Data Writer" listener and give location to save the results. Recommended is with file name with .jtl file type.
2. if you want 2 .jtl files you can add this listener in each thread group. If you want aggregate results then add this listener at test plan level.
3. Once test run is completed you can browse this .jtl file into any desired listener you want, it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

why do you expect 2 generated jtl files since you don’t have any listener.

In this case in non gui mode, jmeter would generate only 1 file, this is what the jmeter-maven-plugin does.

by the way, you’re using an old version 2.1.0 of the plugin, last one is 2.7.0.

Comment: **why do you expect 2 generated jtl files since you don’t have any listener.** Why do I even have 1 `.jtl` coz I dont have a listener at all? Assume both threads ran, then JTL must have data from both the files. Right? After updating the plugin from 2.1.0 to 2.7.0 it doesnt generate `.jtl` it is generating `.csv` file. I think 2nd thread is not running at all, it is getting skipped.

Comment: As I wrote, jmeter-maven-plugin will run jmeter -n -l file.csv -t yourjmx , this is what generates the file. JMeter will never generate bu default 1 csv per thread group. Now regarding the 2nd thread group not running, how many thread and iterations did you set? if not enough since you have a throughput controller at 20% it might not run.

Comment: make sense. So I tried and removed `through put controller` from both threads still only thread1. Now next time I disabled thread1 and ran thread2, reports generated by it was blank and says `waiting for samples`

Comment: when using jmeter-maven-plugin it generates already the jmeter report. Remove the second plugin that you did  and look into target folder, there will be an html report like this: http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html

Comment: It worked with everything like before i.e. with `Through put controller` etc. Problem was actually I had put `apache-jmeter-3.2\bin\testdata` instead `\src\test\jmeter\testdata`. I was going as per the tutorial I read somewhere.

Comment: So if my answer is not the correct one, write your own and accept it so that others know about it. otherwise if you thhink mine is ok, update it and accept it. I think anyway you don’t need additional plugin as html report is generated by jmeter and jmeter-maven-plugin ootb.

Answer (score 0):

While debugging my issue I found that 2nd thread was not even working in GUI mode also. Then I switched the `.csv` files from Thread 1 to 2, found that only 1 `.csv` file always work. Finally, after further digging I found that in order to run your `.csv` in need to be in `src/test/jmeter/testdata` folder and not inside `apache-jmeter-3.2/bin/testdata`.

**Answer:** Second thread was not working because it was using incorrect `.csv`. To find it out click on yellow triangle on top right hand corner in Jmeter GUI. It toggles logs display. Those logs showed me error that `.csv` was not found.

Yes I have also come across few online forums who would tell you to put `.csv` inside `apache-jmeter-3.2\bin\testdata` so that path remain relative i.e. not dependent to project structure or OS. This is CSV parameterization in Jmeter.

So, I would suggest try both, for me it worked inside `src/test/jmeter/testdata` not Jmeter `bin` folder.