# Relative path to jmeter target folder in Jmeter GUI

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-maven-plugin

I want to save Jmeter aggregate report to project's target folder with timestamp,so that everytime I run the tests I get the new unique report, irrespective of OS.

I tried by providing this path `/target/jmeter/results/aggReport.csv` but it saved it in `C:/target/jmeter/results/aggReport.csv` Also there was no time stamp.

E.g. `100320182130aggReport.csv` which is `mmddyyyyhhmmaggReport.csv`

This question is in continuation of soemthing I wanted to achieve here and suggested by Dmitri [Jmeter: Test plan has two thread groups but it generated only 1 jtl report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52575057/jmeter-test-plan-has-two-thread-groups-but-it-generated-only-1-jtl-report/52584940#52584940)

I am using Maven, Java 8, Windows 7

**Update:**

I tried:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. In case of JMeter test execution via Maven JMeter's working directory ([or Java `user.dir` property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html)) points to `target/jmeter/bin` folder so you need to construct the desired path **relative** to it
2. Your path starts with `/` which means it is absolute and points to root folder of the file system
3. You need to include [__time() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time) into the resulting filename if you want the result to be prepended by the timestamp

Assuming all above your listener "Filename" field should look like:

```
../results/${__time(MMddyyyyhhmm,)}aggReport.csv
```

Check out [Five Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui) article for more information on various ways of kicking off a JMeter test including using Maven plugin.

Comment: It didnt work. Updated the question with screenshot.

Comment: *Try running on [JMeter 1.0.2](https://archive.apache.org/dist/jakarta/jmeter/old/release/v1.0/), maybe it will help*. According to JMeter Best Practices you should be using [the latest JMeter version](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version) which is [JMeter 5.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what-is-new-jmeter-5)  as of now, in your case you should be using the latest version of [JMeter Maven Plugin](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin) which is **2.7.0**.  Your "doesn't work" statement is not informative without log files

Comment: I have tried with `Jmeter 5.0` and `Jmeter Maven Plugin 2.7.0`. I am able to get reports with timestamp but this time instead of generating `.jtl` it gave me a combined `.csv` results file. So I have three files 1 combine report (in place of jtl) and two agg reports for each thread.